# Cassandra 1.1 composite keys / columns and hierarchical queries

Tags: cassandra, composite-key, database-indexes

So far, this is what I understand of the current Cassandra architecture:

1. Super columns are not desirable any more due to performance issues.
2. Composite columns (actually keys) are a good choice for indexing hierarchical keys.
3. Composite columns store nested components in sorted order. There is no actual index.

I have some questions:

1. Is everything I stated correct?
2. Can composite columns efficiently process range queries per component (assuming logical usage)?
3. Are composite columns suited to extremely large numbers of rows while still yielding rapid query results (considering they are not an index per se)?
4. Can secondary indexes be created against composite columns. If yes, can range queries be efficiently performed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes, because they are sorted on write just like any other column
4. Yes, secondaries can be created against composites as of 1.2. See this [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3680)

Comment: I saw this article (http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/) that indicates that composite columns don't have to be on keys only. Seems they can be on the key or on any other column.

Comment: @IanC You are correct.  Composites can be used with keys or columns.

Comment: do you know of a good reference that explains this last point? Everything I have found shows composite keys, or hector based queries, but not composite columns.

Comment: @IanC Have you seen [this article](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introduction-to-composite-columns-part-1)?

Comment: I have, but it only shows Hector, not CQL. The only CQL examples I can find show only composite row keys. How does one create composite columns, but not composite keys?

Comment: @IanC Unfortunately I don't use CQL myself, but you can ask in the Cassandra IRC (#cassandra on freenode).  Someone there can surely answer.

Comment: I think of a Composite is just a type, so you can specify a key, (column) name, or value as a Composite. However, using a composite column name can be very powerful, since, as mentioned, the column names are always sorted. Plus, they provide the foundation for CQL3 and primary keys in the [newer schema implementation](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1)

Comment: It turns out that composite columns / keys are the same thing. Sigh. Documentation!

Comment: Yeah, I think documentation is the big issue. At the low level, there are still row keys, which can be a Composite type, which refer to the storage rows.. but, in CQL3, they have "primary keys" which, I believe, are  implemented with Composite (column) names. And that CQL rows are not necessarily 1:1 with storage rows.

Comment: This will probably be an unpopular comment, but I personally steer clear of CQL because it trivializes very important details about the underlying model.  I understand that Cassandra gains somewhat from a language-agnostic query representation, but I am concerned that it's too SQL-like and encourages bad practice.  Just MHO.